# Change VS platform from 4.0 down to 2.0

Tags: .net, target, downgrade

Using MS Visual Studio 2010.
Migrated a project up to .NET 4.0 probably 2 years ago and did significant coding on it.
We don't actually need .NET 4.0, just wanted to keep up with the times.  But now we need a rush release and do not want to include a .net upgrade on top of all other changes.

So, I changed all targets back to .NET 2.0.
When I run, the first time that I hit the app.settings, I get an error
"Unrecognized configuration section connectionStrings. (c:\Folder\Program.vshost.exe.Config line 12)"

If I switch back to .NET 4.0 it goes away.
I checked all references for a reference to a 4.0.0.0 system.*  Nothing found.
I did a text search of *.cs and found files Settings.Designer.cs had a comment referencing it...

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18444
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas where else to look?

Comment: what if you change all the solutions to .Net 2.0 and then do a Clean Solution and then build the solution?  Try that

Comment: Did that.  But now seeing that the release product doesn't seem to run on this PC.  Even after a pristine install (nuke all files and generated files).  So I think my .NET 2.0 subsystem is tanked.  Seems to be just with respect to reading application configuration files.  Going to pursue repairs and whatnot.

Comment: Yep, .NET 2.0 framework had become damaged.  All programs that used System.Configuration under the 2.0 framework were failing.  And what caused it?  I happened to install Visual Studio 2013 last Thursday.  I used a restore point from before that to regain correct behavior.  Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out my .NET 2.0 System.Configuration had become broken (anything that used an app.config file).  The telltale sign was when I did a fresh install of our released product that works on thousands of computers and it failed the same way as my development code that I was trying to re-target.

I restored my computer back to last Thursday and all went fine again.  Re-targeting of the project in Visual Studio 2010 works flawlessly.

What did I do last Thursday?  I installed Visual Studio 2013...  I also installed some free menu-creators for the auto-run of a CD-ROM.  I will be a lot more cautious if I try any of those products again.